# Scala compilation failures

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I have some code, which compiles (scala 2.9.1) a scala class "on the fly" (i.e. invokes the scala compiler from the scala application code in runtime)

*Sometimes* the compilation fails (see below).
Can you explain what it is and how to fix that ?

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer.bridgeDefs(Erasure.scala:875)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer.addBridges(Erasure.scala:956)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anon$3.preErase(Erasure.scala:1135
```

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
  at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:89)
  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.InfoTransformers$InfoTransformer.insert(InfoTransformers.scala:21)  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.InfoTransformers$InfoTransformer.insert(InfoTransformers.scala:25)
  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.InfoTransformers$InfoTransformer.insert(InfoTransformers.scala:25)
```

```
java.lang.Error: no-symbol does not have owner
  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolTable.abort(SymbolTable.scala:34)
  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Symbols$NoSymbol$.owner(Symbols.scala:2150)
  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anon$3.preErase(Erasure.scala:1112)
  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anon$3.transform(Erasure.scala:1157)
```

Comment: And can you give a snippet of code which you compile?

Comment: Are you ensuring that you only use a given instance of Global in a single threaded fashion?

Comment: @retronym Thanks a lot ! I did not check it. Do these errors/exceptions indicate that Global is invoked concurrently ?

Comment: @Rogach Sincerely I do not think these errors have anything to do with the code to compile. It looks like some "environment" problem.

Comment: If you access it concurrently, all bets are off, and it could fail in almost any way.

Comment: @retronym Thank you again. I have found where Global is invoked concurrently in the code. Your remark did help me!